# MYSQL - Order a table by another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem
I have two tables

The table "Memes"

```
id       imglink      name
----------------------------------
1        img.Png      Polite cat
2        img2.png     Crying cat
```

And the table "Vote"

```
id    idmeme    vote
---------------------
1     1           5
2     1           2
3     2           4
```

So basically the table "meme" contains memes with their image and their name
And the table "votes" contains the notes on 5 that users assign to the memes

I would like my sql query to rank by the same the highest rated with the highest rating

I already look at other topic but the problem is that for each vote with the id of the same it duplicates in the result of the SELECT *

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is to use a subquery right in the `order by`:

```
select m.*
from memes m
order by (select max(v.vote) from vote v where v.idmeme = m.id);
```

Of course, you can also include this in the `from` clause (as an aggregation query) and use a `join`.

Comment: I do not know why but the polite cat is first so he has a score of 2.3 and the others have a score of 3

Comment: The default for ORDER BY is *ascending* so a value of ***`2.3`*** would come before a value of ***`3`***. If we want the highest values first, we can add the keyword `DESC`, .i.e. **`ORDER BY some_expresssion DESC`**

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way is to use a query that returns all the maximum votes from `Vote` and join it to the table:

```
select m.*
from Memes m left join (
  select idmeme, max(vote) vote
  from Vote
  group by idmeme
)v on v.idmeme = m.id
order by v.vote desc, m.name
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6JrXmwUjh7CVzFbwFXCtc9/2).
Results:

```
| id  | imglink  | name       |
| --- | -------- | ---------- |
| 1   | img.Png  | Polite cat |
| 2   | img2.png | Crying cat |
```